# Sending header data in Azure eventhub using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am sending a message to an Azure event hub using the standard code provided by microsoft and it works fine, However, I would also like to add a header to each message to know additional details about the message. I am unable to find ways to do it, below is my attempy which didnt work.

```
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, username=USER, password=KEY, debug=True)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="0", send_timeout=2000, keep_alive=500)
    client.run()
    try:
        nevent_data = EventData('Message with properties')
        nevent_data.properties = {'prop': 'prop1'}
        sender.send(nevent_data)
```

In this I am trying to send properties in the form of a dict along with message body , the below is the listener.

Listener :

```
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
try:
    receiver = client.add_receiver(
        CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=5000, offset=OFFSET)
    client.run()
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=1):
            print(event_data.properties)
            print("Received: {}".format(event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))
```

when I try to get the properties , it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing one parameter in the above will work.

Change

```
nevent_data.properties = {'prop': 'prop1'}
```

To

```
nevent_data.application_properties = {'prop': 'prop1'}
```

On the reciever do the same.

```
print(event_data.application_properties)
```